# How to get result from boundFn

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just digging into Vue.JS and I'm having a problem with getting function result from Vue instance.

```
var DS = {
    getOne: function(){ return 1 }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js',
  },
  methods: {
    greet: function (event) {
      var data = DS.getOne
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
})
```

I was thinking that DS.getOne should be already calculated, however I'm getting boundFn in console. Is there a way to compute that function? Where could I read something more to understand this issue?

```
ƒ boundFn(a) {
    var l = arguments.length;
    return l
      ? l > 1
        ? fn.apply(ctx, arguments)
        : fn.call(ctx, a)
      : fn.call(ctx)
  }
```

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/jvj5u637/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DS.getOne` is pointing to a function, not to the number `1` as you'd expect.

You can do one of two things:

**First option**: instead of setting `data` equal to `DS.getOne`, set it to `DS.getOne()` -- the difference is that you will be calling the `DS.getOne` function, which returns 1:

```
var data = DS.getOne(); // DS.getOne() returns 1
```

**Second option**: If you want `DS.getOne` to point to `1` directly, then you need the function to run immediately when you define `getOne`:

```
var DS = {
    getOne: (function(){ return 1 })() // evaluates to 1
};
```

**Edit:** I modified your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0n7ofpk/) with the First Option mentioned above. The alert now correctly prints `1`

Comment: How do we get a reference to the *actual* function, and not the result? So it can be called later